# xcode - Is there a way to instruct xcode to compile intel syntax inline assembly in C projects?

Tags: xcode, inline-assembly

I have downloaded the Quake III Arena source, made a Xcode-project of it, and now the build fails as the underlying compiler (gcc?) encounters **Intel syntax** inline assembly in one/several C-files.

Assuming that the compiler knows how to handle Intel syntax if a proper switch is passed to it, is there a way to instruct the Xcode to pass such switch to the underlying compiler?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which compiler are you using? (Select project then select build settings, under Build Options header)